# Javascript this returns different values

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm creating a simple Backbone.js todo list.

In my Views initialize, I have:

```
    var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
        render: function() {
            var html = '<input type="text" value="' + this.model.get('title') + '">';
            $(this.el).html(html);
        },
       initialize: function () {
            var thisView = this;
            console.log(thisView.model.toJSON()); // <- this works
            $(this.el).change(function (thisView) {
                console.log(thisView.model.toJSON()); // <- thisView is not View here
                thisView.model.set('title', $(this).val());
            });
       }
    });
```

I've also tried this:

```
       setTitle: function () {
           console.log(this); // <- this doesn't return View
       },

       initialize: function () {
           $(this.el).change(this.setTitle)
       }
```

Comment: You're overriding the variable by declaring it as the function parameter `function (thisView)`. Is that intended?

Comment: I wanted to pass variable to the function...

Comment: The function already has access to `thisView` because of closure. What you're doing is calling the first parameter of the function `thisView` also, which is overriding the value. The first parameter of the `.change` callback is the event object.

Comment: Yes, `function()` works!

Comment: @Stryner how about the secend code? that's not a closure so doesn't has access to `thisView`... how can I pass my View object to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback of the `change`, `click` and other jQuery 'events' methods in Javascript take one and only one argument: the event that was triggered.

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
        var html = '<input type="text" value="' + this.model.get('title') + '">';
        $(this.el).html(html);
    },
   initialize: function () {
        var thisView = this;
        console.log(thisView.model.toJSON()); // <- this works
        $(this.el).change(function (event) {
            console.log(thisView.model.toJSON()); // <- this works also
            thisView.model.set('title', $(this).val());
        });
   }
});
```

But you should not do it this way. You should almost never call directly jQuery `$`. You should use the event property of the view, instead.

For the second part, you can either do this:

```
initialize: function () {
    var view = this;
    $(this.el).change(function () {
        view.setTitle();
    });
}
```

Or this:

```
initialize: function () {
    var view = this;
    // Beware: the first and only argument that setTitle() will receive is the event
    $(this.el).change(this.setTitle.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you help me with the second code? in the `setTitle` function, `this` returns jQuery object (`<div>`) and `thisView` is not defined.

Comment: Where do you call `setTitle()` from?

Comment: in the initialize : `initialize: function () {
           $(this.el).change(this.setTitle)
       }`